# How to change number of rows of a GridPane programmatically?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm trying to create a **`GridPane`** with fixed number of columns but **variable number of rows** (according to how many elements I want to insert in my view).

I prepared the fxml relative to each element all inside a `VBox`.

The result I would like to obtain is something like this

```
+---+  +---+  +---+
|   |  |   |  |   |
+---+  +---+  +---+

+---+  +---+  +---+
|   |  |   |  |   |
+---+  +---+  +---+

+---+  +---+  
|   |  |   |  
+---+  +---+
```

With number of elements varying according to how many elements I have in my database.

How to insert **custom elements in a `GridPane`**

How to make its number of rows **programmatically changeable**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GridPane#addRow(int, Node...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#addRow-int-javafx.scene.Node...-)

```
AtomicInteger rowCount = new AtomicInteger();
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
gp.setGridLinesVisible(true);
Button b = new Button("Add Row");
b.setOnAction( e-> gp.addRow(rowCount.getAndIncrement(),
        new Label("Row" + (rowCount.get()-1) + " Col1"),
        new Label("Row" + (rowCount.get()-1) + " Col2")));
```

Each `Node` in the vararg argument will be placed into a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a general approach that you could implement in a larger code base

If we create the following as variables

```
private final GridPane grid = new GridPane();

private Item[][] items;
private int columnCount = 0;
private int rowCount = 0;
```

below is a method that will update a grid pane using set column and row index methods

```
/**
 * Should be called whenever items array changes.
 */
private void render() {

    List<Item> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
            Item item = getItemAt(column, row);

            // if it is null it wont be painted e.g. empty/blank item
            if (item != null) {
                toAdd.add(item);
                GridPane.setColumnIndex(item, item.getColumn());
                GridPane.setRowIndex(item, item.getRow());
            }
        }
    }

    // add all at once for better performance
    grid.getChildren().setAll(toAdd);
}
```

here is a gist for the rest of the class
https://gist.github.com/nsavageJVM/5775128a9682ebcf0e8186ff209f4f8e